# Data not exporting correctly into .csv from Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Though I can display all the data to the terminal; when it exports, the Hostname columns fills with
`System.Object[]`. I need to add to more columns, but in previous attemps thy also populated with
Example:
[oUTPUT_eXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9axYx.png)

## Retrieve host information

```
$hosts = Get-VMHost
```

## Initialize an empty array to store the data

```
$serviceTags = @()
```

## Loop through each host

```
foreach ($hostsname in $hosts) 
 {
    **#Retrieve Datacenter, hostName and Model**
    $mydatacenter = Get-Datacenter -VMHost $hosts
    write-host "Completed Datacenter..."
    $vhostName = $hosts.Name
    write-host "Completed Hosts..."
    $model = $hosts.ExtensionData.Summary.Hardware.Model
    write-host "Completed Model..."   
    $serviceTag = ($hostsname| Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo |
        Where-Object { $_.IdentifierType.Key -eq "ServiceTag" } |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifierValue
    write-host "Completed ServiceTag"

   # Create a custom object with Datacenter, host name Model and service tag

    $serviceTagInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
       DataCenter = $mydatacenter
       HostName = $vhostName
       Model = $model
       ServiceTag = $serviceTag
       }

    # Add the object to the array
    $serviceTags += $serviceTagInfo

}
# Export the data to CSV
$serviceTags | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Users\myuser\Documents\ServiceTags2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're iterating over `$hosts` and you're querying `$hosts` again: `$mydatacenter = Get-Datacenter -VMHost $hosts` instead of `$hostsname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$vhostName = $hosts.Name
```

works by expanding the `Name` field of the `$hosts` array into an **array** of strings of all the names. It's equivalent to

```
$vhostName = $hosts | foreach {$_.Name}
```

It's called [member-access-enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration?view=powershell-7.3).

Since `$vhostName` is an array it gets expanded to `System.Object[]` in your output. Since your already iterating through `$hosts` just use the current `$hostname` struct:

```
$vhostName = $hostname.Name
```